# Sense-like context menus?

Tags: android, android-contextmenu, sense

I've noticed some programs use a popup toolbar for context menus instead of actual context menus, like in Sense (see image:)

[image]

How would I go about implementing something like that?

Comment: Where you able to achieve this? Because I am working on the same thing, and having problems with positioning the popup box above the selection .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's called a Quick Actions Popup, you have to create it yourself.

Refer this [LINK](http://www.londatiga.net/it/how-to-create-quickaction-dialog-in-android/).

Sample code snippet::

```
//Add action item
ActionItem addAction = new ActionItem();
addAction.setTitle("Add");
addAction.setIcon(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.ic_add));

//Accept action item
ActionItem accAction = new ActionItem();

accAction.setTitle("Accept");
accAction.setIcon(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.ic_accept));

//Upload action item
ActionItem upAction = new ActionItem();
upAction.setTitle("Upload");
upAction.setIcon(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.ic_up));
```

Create quickaction instance and setup listener

```
final QuickAction mQuickAction  = new QuickAction(this);

mQuickAction.addActionItem(addAction);
mQuickAction.addActionItem(accAction);
mQuickAction.addActionItem(upAction);

//setup the action item click listener
mQuickAction.setOnActionItemClickListener(new QuickAction.OnActionItemClickListener() {
    @Override
        public void onItemClick(int pos) {
        if (pos == 0) { //Add item selected
           Toast.makeText(Example1Activity.this, "Add item selected", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        } else if (pos == 1) { //Accept item selected
           Toast.makeText(Example1Activity.this, "Accept item selected", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        } else if (pos == 2) { //Upload item selected
           Toast.makeText(Example1Activity.this, "Upload items selected", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    }
});
```

Comment: Ah, thanks. Sometimes it's all about knowing **what** to look for :-)

Answer (score 1):

these links correspond to exactly your needs, by the way this popup tool is called QuickAction:

[QuickAction](https://github.com/lorensiuswlt/NewQuickAction3D)

[QuickAction Dialog](http://www.londatiga.net/it/how-to-create-quickaction-dialog-in-android/)

[Green Droid QuickAction](http://android.cyrilmottier.com/?p=347)

[image: QuickActionBar and GridAction]

Hope this will help you